# Show that every matrix with real eigenvalue less than $0$ is similar to dissipative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices, hurwitz-matrices

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. $A$ is dissipative if $A+A^T \prec 0$. How do I show that $A$ is similar to a dissipative matrix?

I started by showing that the eigenvalue of $A$ is real and less than zero but I can't think of any way to proceed ahead. I think it would be helpful to use some type of matrix decomposition, perhaps Schur decomposition? Please advise.

Comment: What does $<$ mean in this context?

Comment: By "<" it means the matrix A + A^T is negative definite i.e. eigenvalue is real and less than 0.

Comment: It also means that A+A^T is symmetric

Comment: And when you say "every real matrix with eigenvalue less than 0", do you mean "every real matrix with all eigenvalues less than 0"?

Comment: Yes. All eigenvalues are less than zero

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a dynamic systems view on this using continuous dynamic systems in state-space representation.
Particularly, a system represented by the equation
$$
\dfrac{\mathbb{d}\vec{x}(t)}{\mathbb{d}t} = \mathbf{A} \vec{x}(t)
,\; \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}
,\; \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n
.
$$
It can be shown that the time response of such system is given by
$$
\vec{x}(t) = e^{\mathbf{A}t} \vec{x}(0)
,\; t \geq 0
,
$$
where $\vec{x}(0)$ are the initial conditions at time $t=0$.

Let
$$
\mathbf{V} = \begin{bmatrix} \vec{v_1} & \vec{v_2} & \cdots & \vec{v_n} \end{bmatrix}
,
$$
where $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}, \dotsc, \vec{v_n}\}$ are the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$.
Then, using $\mathbf{V}$ as a transformation matrix
$$
\mathbf{\Lambda} = \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{V}
.
$$
$\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is said to be the Jordan form of $\mathbf{A}$. It looks like
$$
\mathbf{\Lambda} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_5 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
,
$$
where $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dotsc, \lambda_n\}$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \lambda_4$ are repeated eigenvalues.
Notice the $1$s above the repeated $\lambda_2$; they may or may not appear above repeated eigenvalues.
Then
$$
e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t} =
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\lambda_1 t} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & e^{\lambda_2 t} & \dfrac{t e^{\lambda_2 t}}{1!} & \dfrac{t^2 e^{\lambda_2 t}}{2!} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{\lambda_2 t} & \dfrac{t e^{\lambda_2 t}}{1!} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\lambda_2 t} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{\lambda_5 t} & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & e^{\lambda_n t} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Also, it can be shown that
$$
e^{\mathbf{A}t} = \mathbf{V} e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t} \mathbf{V}^{-1}
$$
which applied to the system time response, gives
$$
\vec{x}(t) = \mathbf{V} e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \vec{x}(0)
,\; t \geq 0
$$

Suppose $\vec{x}(0) \neq \vec{0}$. Then, $\vec{x}(t) \to \vec{0} \iff e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t} \to \mathbf{0}$; that is, all states decay (or dissipate energy) if and only if every element in $e^{\mathbf{\Lambda}t}$ goes to zero over time.
All elements are either already zero or $t^k e^{\lambda t},\; k \geq 0$, which tends to zero if and only if $\Re(\lambda) < 0$; that is, the real part of $\lambda$ is negative.

Thus, $\mathbf{A}$ is dissipative if and only if the real part of all of its eigenvalues are negative, which implies it is negative definite, which implies $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{A}^T < \mathbf{0}$.